# Weird behaviour spry tabbed panels

Tags: php, css, spry

I have been working several of hours on creating an form for people to enter their contact information. The tabbed panel is displayed vertically where it should be displayed horizontally. (http://www.ski-inndronten.nl/boeken/boeken1new.php?deelnemers=5)

When I change the position of the form tag to somewhere within the

```
<div class="TabbedPanelsContentGroup">
```

you will get the following result:
http://www.ski-inndronten.nl/boeken/boeken1.php?deelnemers=5

(the page doesnt get tabbed)

It's a Dutch website, so don't mind the Dutch language. 
I think I am messing up some tags, but am not able to debug it whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Its two weeks late - but it seems while inserting data into your spry tabs you have deleted `</div>` in the second panel somewhere - as there is a lot of content there I cannot seem to see it.

I fixed your code copy from here - http://friendpaste.com/6sFBenu4SC4zRaJYfHpjf9

Comment: If that doesn't fix the problem there may be more unopened/unclosed tags left. You can use for example [this w3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to find and eliminate those problems (as well as a few others). For example, see [this check](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ski-inndronten.nl%2Fboeken%2Fboeken1.php%3Fdeelnemers%3D5) of the link given in the question.

Comment: The code I fixed works as I tested it. I basically rebuilt it - tab by tab - for him. But the validator is coming up with tones of other mistakes!